# .Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to connect to access database using SQL Server Management Studio and I am getting the abvoe error in Title.  Here is my code:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server= N'\\HSS-SQLEXPRESS\HSSSQLE',                     
@provider= N'SQLNCLI',                                         
@srvproduct= N' ',                                         
@datasrc=N'\\HSS-HSS-SQLEXPRESS\HSSSQLE\Data\Testing.accdb',         
GO
```

The syntax for @datasrc is giving the error.
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma after the `@datasrc` parameter value:

`@datasrc=N'\\HSS-HSS-SQLEXPRESS\HSSSQLE\Data\Testing.accdb'`

Your last paramter value cannot be followed by `,`